# How to use FtpCommand to get something like the system type?

Tags: c#, ftp

I was curious if there is any way to use [`FtpCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Wininet/nf-wininet-ftpcommanda) to get data from the ftp server, for example, just like in the title, if I use the command `SYST`, is there a way to get the returned value, the system's type?

On the page linked above there is `phFtpCommand` ("`A pointer to a handle that is created if a valid data socket is opened. The fExpectResponse parameter must be set to TRUE for phFtpCommand to be filled.`"), but from what I have seen there is no function that uses the data socket handle, or is this handle the data itself?